# Why the firestore isn't working on android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I try to implement firestore on my android project. I have follow everything on the official firebase wesbite. I am getting those errors :

```
2020-11-03 19:38:47.569 8695-8760/com.example.alllerrr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-okhttp-0
Process: com.example.alllerrr, PID: 8695
java.lang.AssertionError: Method getAlpnSelectedProtocol not supported for object SSL socket over Socket[address=firestore.googleapis.com/172.217.19.234,port=443,localPort=46122]
    at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.OptionalMethod.invoke(OptionalMethod.java:114)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.OptionalMethod.invokeWithoutCheckedException(OptionalMethod.java:135)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.getSelectedProtocol(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:183)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:145)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:571)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have implemented okhttp and put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

on the manifest file. But nothing is working: the app is still crashing.
Here is my code:

```
val userID = auth.currentUser
                db.collection("users").document(userID.toString())
                val Map = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                Map["pseudo"] = name.toString()
                db.collection("users")
                        .add(Map)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "succes:" + userID,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Veuillez essayer plus tard.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
```

(I have tried tu put String instead of the "Any" in the hashmap variable.) If anyone have a clue!

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2703

Comment: Well it cannot be because of the version or age of the phone I'm using, it's android 11... My google play services is up to date so that's why I don't understand...

Comment: As the link Doug provided indicated that you should use [the dynamic security provider](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I experienced the same thing on android 11 and got around it by adding the following to my `build.gradle` file

`implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"`

Comment: thanks, this works for me!
insert in android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 11):

as the below answer add in android/app/build.gradle
in dependencies section

```
dependencies {
    ....
    .....
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did try a solution from Joseph Geoffery

- Open `build.gradle` file in your app folder
- Add this in dependencies section

  ```
  implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"
  ```

this work for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29863155)