# Does the error below relate to my firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am currently creating an app and after I have run it, everything was fine until subsequently the whole app crashes and this error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Method getAlpnSelectedProtocol not supported for object SSL socket over Socket[address=firestore.googleapis.com/142.251.12.95,port=443,localPort=60896]
```

pops up. I have been trying to search for any solutions to this issue and have checked my firestore side but yet I am still unable to fix this. can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyone here who faced the same problem as you maybe this will help you.

[Why the firestore isn't working on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668851/why-the-firestore-isnt-working-on-android-studio)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).