# Crashlytics mapping file upload fails on Android Studio with minifyEnabled

Tags: android, firebase, proxy, proguard, crashlytics

When activating proguard (*minifyEnabled = true*) in my gradle configuration, the build fails in the step:
**:app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease**

the returned error is: **java.io.IOException: Crashlytics could not read proxy port string**

With *minifyEnabled = false* the app builds and runs correctly.

My gradle file (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId project.getProperties().get('application_id')
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.getProperties().get('version_code'))
        versionName project.getProperties().get('version_name')
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resValue 'string', 'application_name', project.getProperties().get('application_name')
        resValue 'string', 'application_id', project.getProperties().get('application_id')
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../' + project.getProperties().get('store_file'))
            storePassword project.getProperties().get('store_password')
            keyAlias project.getProperties().get('key_alias')
            keyPassword project.getProperties().get('key_password')
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            firebaseAppDistribution {
                releaseNotes = generateChangeLogShort()
                testers = "john.doe@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    // KTX
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

    // Needed for https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4651
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'

    // Firebase bug workaround for emulator, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668851/why-the-firestore-isnt-working-on-android-studio
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.44.1"

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')

    // Declare the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.10.7'
    implementation 'androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.1.0'

    // Navigation:
    def nav_version = "2.5.0"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Places library
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.6.0'
    // PING Place Picker
    implementation project(path: ':pingplacepicker')
    //Wheel Picker
    implementation 'com.super_rabbit.wheel_picker:NumberPicker:1.0.1'

    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}

def generateChangeLogShort(){
    println "Generating release notes"
    def releaseNotes = ""
    def lastTagHash = "git rev-list --tags --skip=1 --max-count=1".execute().text.trim()
    println lastTagHash
    def lastTag = "git describe --abbrev=0 --tags $lastTagHash".execute().text.trim()
    println lastTag
    def cmdLine = "git log $lastTag..head --pretty=format:\"%s\""
    def procCommit = cmdLine.execute()

    procCommit.in.eachLine { line ->
        //Remove surrounding quotation marks generated by the git log command
        def escapedLine = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1)
        //Escape backslashes
        escapedLine = escapedLine.replaceAll(/(\\)/, "\\/")
        //Escape quotation marks
        escapedLine = escapedLine.replaceAll('"', '\\\\"')

        //if (escapedLine.startsWith("feat:")) {
            releaseNotes += escapedLine + "\n"
        //}
    }

    println releaseNotes
    return releaseNotes
}
```

gradle file (project):

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        def nav_version = '2.4.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.10.1'
        classpath 'io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:2.9.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:3.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
}
```

The error stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Crashlytics could not read proxy port string.
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.net.proxy.DefaultProxyFactory.create(DefaultProxyFactory.java:38)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.RestfulWebApi.sendFile(RestfulWebApi.java:91)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.RestfulWebApi.uploadFile(RestfulWebApi.java:119)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.api.FirebaseMappingFileService.uploadMappingFile(FirebaseMappingFileService.java:44)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.uploadMappingFile(Buildtools.java:208)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools$uploadMappingFile$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.UploadMappingFileTask.uploadMappingFile(UploadMappingFileTask.groovy:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    ... 114 more
```

**UPDATE:**
Found out that issue is that the Crashlytics mapping file can't be uploaded because the proxy settings are not set in the Androdi Studio environment. But no proxy is being used, so have no idea what to specify for:
*systemProp.https.proxyPort
systemProp.https.proxyHost*

Comment: Are you behind a corporate network? There could be a firewall or a proxy that could be blocking these requests. Also, is this happening with the latest Crashlytics SDK version? Check this related to the domains used by Crashlytics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74608162/4044241

Comment: Did you ever solve your issue?

Comment: Any solution? 
@Emanuel how about you? Did you find out what is the root cause?

Comment: @Mahdi I posted an answer. Adding the firebase / crashlytics url's to nonProxyHosts settings fixed it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem. I'm behind a VPN and added proxy settings in **gradle.properties** (Project Properties). You can find my settings below. The whitelabeling of crashlytics was important in my case.
(for security reasons I changed the corporate domains)

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=some.web.proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=some.web.proxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.companydomain.com|localhost|*.crashlytics.com|crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com|firebasecrashlyticssymbols.googleapis.com
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.companydomain.com|localhost|*.crashlytics.com|crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com|firebasecrashlyticssymbols.googleapis.com
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```