# Firebase Crashlytics for Android app without internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have a setup that looks something like this

```
    App        WiFi but no          Hardware
  ┌─────┐       internet         ┌────────────┐  WiFi with internet
  │     │                        │            │
  │     │ ─────────────────────► │            │  ────────────►
  │     │                        │            │
  │     │ ◄───────────────────── │            │  ◄────────────
  │     │                        │            │
  └─────┘                        └────────────┘
```

I.e. my Android app does not have direct access to the internet, but the hardware it talks to has.

Is it possible to implement Firebase Crashlytics here? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: can please clarify the problem in detail that gives me a brief idea about what you are trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

The Crashlytics SDK will try to connect with the Crashlytics endpoints when uploading crash reports. In this configuration I don't think it will be able to do so.

Are you able to restrict access to some endpoints? If so, a possible workaround could be allowing the Crashlytics domains so the SDK can upload them. These are the domains used by Crashlytics on ports 80 and 443:

```
*.crashlytics.com
crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com
firebasecrashlyticssymbols.googleapis.com
```